# Jquery Scroll to Top + Offset it so it doesn't go under my menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrolltop

This is what I have

```
    $('.option-heading, .speaker_container').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

It works, but it scrolls to the top and push the top of the new div under my menu.  I need to margin it down by 62px;  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was putting it in the wrong spot and it should be a minus sign :]

Here is the answer:
`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this).offset().top - 62)}, 'slow');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this).offset().top + 62)}, 'slow');
```